# jQuery slideToggle() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a div (.panel divs) appear or disappear when the div right above that one (.accordion divs) is clicked.

I've tryed several variatons for the jQuery code but none have worked for me.

I know I'm doing something wrong but can't find what, so this is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion">Section 4</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 5</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 6</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
$(".panel").hide();

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("test");
        $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
    });
}
```

With what I have so far I can hide the `.panel` divs, and the `test` console log prints correctly, but once I click on the correspondig `.accordion` div, I get the following error message:

> TypeError: $(...).next(...).slideToggle is not a function

Comment: Slim doesn't contain animation, so it doesn't have any of the `slideXXX()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix both pure JavaScript and jQuery. Use this way:

```
$(".panel").hide();

$(".accordion").click(function () {
  if ($(this).next(".panel").is("visible"))
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
  else {
    $(".panel:visible").slideUp();
    $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
  }
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".panel").hide();

  $(".accordion").click(function() {
    if ($(this).next(".panel").is("visible"))
      $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
    else {
      $(".panel:visible").slideUp();
      $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">Section 4</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 5</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 6</div>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Reason why yours didn't work is you need to use closures. The context of `this` in your code differs when it is run through the `for` loop.

Comment: This doesn't explain why his code doesn't work. Mixing plain JS and jQuery may be confusing, but it should still work.

Comment: @Barmar Sure... But I am sure it will work if closures are used.

Comment: This doesn't solve OPs issue either. Take a look at my answer for desired results. He wants to create an accordion that only allows one tab to open at a time.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Ah... Okay.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Why does he need to use a closure? The callback function doesn't use any of the outside variables.

Comment: @Barmar Slightly confused. Sorry?

Comment: `addEventListener` sets `this` in the callback function the same way that `.click()` does.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want? On each click, you first slide all `.panels` up, then slide the clicked panel down:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
$(".panel").hide();

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("test");
        $('.panel').slideUp();
        $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle();
    });
}
```

```css
.panel {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">Section 4</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 5</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<div class="accordion">Section 6</div>
<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Because this is not causing an error and giving desired results? What are you expecting?

Comment: The question is about the `$(...).next(...).slideToggle is not a function` error.

Comment: Hmm, well it seems like there are really two questions. 1) How can I close the other panels when I click on a panel and 2) why am I getting this error? Solving the first question makes the second question null. Would love for OP to chime in here.

Comment: @Barmar Chase uses normal jQuery here. Not sure why you asked this question.

Comment: @Barmar I copied OPs code example to my answer. If it is not setup the same as their app then they should update their example.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I meant that question for the OP.

Comment: I tryed this, but now I'm getting `TypeError: $(...).slideUp is not a function`

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I turned the code in the original question into a stack snippet. There was no version of jQuery specified in the original code.

Comment: @Barmar Got ya. `:)`

Comment: Well maybe don't do that next time :) your assumption has caused a lot of confusion. Please let OP drive those decisions.